# Is there a way to generate graphs of qml component dependencies?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am working in a project which uses qml and has a lot of components in components in components, there are so many that sometimes they look like magically appearing. So I was wondering...

Is there a tool or some way to generate graphs of qml component dependencies?
(So I can see a root component with the childs and grandchildren and so on, to see a picture of this, so I can better visualize it.)